# Will Microservices Architecture Speed Up Spring Boot Startup Time?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, microservices, spring-cloud

I have a **Spring Boot application with Gradle** that currently is taking a lot of time.
Now, is taking about 10 minutes plus just to startup.
The source code indeed is growing rapidly, 6 Months ago, it only taking 3 minutes plus to startup.

**Possible Causes**

Here are facts that I think are causing the slowness:

1. Usage of Hibernate: current source code uses a lot of sql queries.
   In fact, I cant use hibernate.show_sql since it will make the startup time longer
   with never ending logs keep showing up.
2. There are 160+ entities with each entity is for a table.
3. There are 20+ schedulers.
4. There are 60+ dependencies used

**Thought on Microservice**

I just learnt the concept of Microsevice where
it breaks down an application to smaller pieces.
So, with that, would it possibly speed up the startup time?

1. I have tried to comment Schedulers during
   startup time in my local, but still takes 10 mins plus
2. I have used spring.main.lazy-initalization = true
   but still takes 9 mins plus
3. I used
   org.gradle.paralel = true, still takes 10 mins plus

Comment: Gradle is just a build tool, it should never be used to run an application in production. To the question: If we do not know where startup time is spent, the question cannot be answered. Most probably startup time improves. Maybe it improves for some microservices, but not for others. The startup time, however, should not be the reason to switch architecture.

Comment: This sounds like a traditional giant monolithic application.  It's impossible for us to tell you how to speed it up.  Microservices are like any other tool - they may help but it will take time to learn the correct way to implement and deploy.  Based on your first bullet point it sounds like there is a good amount of DB interaction on startup.  Where is the DB hosted?  You need to do some detailed analysis to determine why the startup is so slow.  Logging and timings will be a start.

Comment: I doubt your issue is related to microservices/monolitic architecture, we have one HBN application with 700+ entities and HBN's contribution in startup delay is about 30-60 seconds (all that time HBN is generating bytebuddy proxies), most probably you are doing some wrong things when spring is constructing context.